# I Cant Reach Vector of Class Methods ! What should i do?

Tags: c++

```
**Its header file**

#ifndef MUSTERI_H
#define MUSTERI_H
#include <string>

using std::string;


class Musteri
{
   public:
        string ad;
        void SetAd(string);
        string GetAd();
};
#endif
```

**its cpp file**

```
#include "Musteri.h"
#include <string>

void Musteri::SetAd(string deger)
{
    ad=deger;
}

string Musteri::GetAd()
{
    return ad; 
}
```

**its Main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

vector <Musteri> musteriler;

Musteri musteri_x;

musteri_x.SetAd("John");
musteri_x.SetSoyad("Wick");

musteriler.push_back(musteri_x);

musteri_x.SetAd("Jena");
musteri_x.SetSoyad("Rick");

musteriler.push_back(musteri_x);

cout<<musteriler[0].GetAd();//its not working

return 1;
}
```

cout<<musteriler[0].GetAd()
i cant reach methods like this
please help me.what should i do? how i can reach vector of a class ?
detail detail detail detail detail detail detail detail detail

Comment: "detail detail detail detail detail detail detail detail detail" - *Don't'*.

Comment: sorry i couldnt think another detail :D

Comment: You should pass the `std::string` class by reference or by constant reference if the function doesn't modify the parameter.

Comment: You need to `#include <iostream>` and `using std::cout;` or change `cout` to `std::cout`.

Comment: Since your structure contains `std::string`, you should write a copy constructor.  In some cases, the compiler will generate one for you.

Comment: Try using the `GetAd()` method with `musteri_x`.  This will prove you can *reach* the value.

Comment: Lastly, you should place a breakpoint at the `cout` statement, then *step into* the function and see what values are being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you have posted (which is apparently incomplete, as your definition of class Musteri does not contain any member function called SetSoyad...) and a quite unclear question, one can only guess what your problem is. What does "I can't reach" mean?

However I have a feeling that you have problem with either header files or namespaces. If you want to use std::vector, you must include the  header. Similarly for std::cout you need . Both these names need to be prefixed by std:: since they live in the standard namespace.

Comment: Sorry,its working.Just i couldnt see on function list :)